# mixin down-side mentioned in vue's docs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

There's this mentioned in the docs why mixin has a down-side in Vue 2.

> Reusability is limited: we cannot pass any parameters to the mixin to
> change its logic which reduces their flexibility in terms of
> abstracting logic

I kind of don't understand this in a complete manner.. If we have a mixin which has the functions that do some part of the business logic. What I can do is from the component, call this mixin's functions and pass parameters to those functions. What does Vue mean that by the words above ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it boils down to parameters that effects state on initialization. With mixins you would have to pass these parameters to each mixin function e.g.

```
var myUserMixin = {
  methods: {
    hello: function (user) {
      console.log(`hello ${user.name}!`)
    }
    goodbye: function (user) {
      console.log(`Bye ${user.name}!`)
    }
  }
}
```

Versus Vue 3 composable:

```
export default function useMyUser (user) {
  function hello() {
    console.log(`hello ${user.name}!`)
  }
  function goodbye() {
    console.log(`Bye ${user.name}!`)
  }
  return {
    hello,
    goodbye
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Beyers, could you take a look at this too ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64773093/vue-composition-api-how-does-it-solve-naming-conflicts